# ActionBar Icons having different sizes

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

In my android application, some of the action bar icons are at normal size (like the star in the screenshot) and some are too small (like the browser and the share icon in the screenshot).

[image: Screenshot]

All of the Icons are added in the exact same way:

```
menu.add(getString(R.string.sync)).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_sync)
```

This happens in three of my activities with different icons. The image files are in the correct directories for their density, they are all from the ActionBar Icon Pack and do all look the same size in the directory on the computer.

I use ActionBarSherlock to display the Actionbar on Gingerbread, but it looks exactly the same on ICS/JB, where ActionBarSherlock should use the native ActionBar (so I guess it's not ABSherlock's fault).

I have no idea, what the reason of this could be.

Comment: can u tell us what the width x height of each of those icons for say mdpi?

Comment: It is probably the case that those images have too much transparent padding in them. If the image is larger than 32dps, then they will be shrunk in the action bar. So, crop those images down to 32dps and you should be OK.

Comment: Thanks pents90! that was the case for me

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your icon drawable resources are not the correct size. To fix this, you will need to recreate your icons.

When you do this, be sure to check the [Android Design- Iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) page to ensure that you are creating your resources at the right resolution.

Comment: I don't believe this is the solution because all PNG files came directly from the Android Design pack and were not modified at all. In other projects, those icon files work.

Comment: Do you have the correct density icons in the correct folders (eg the hdpi icons in a drawables-hdpi folder)?